# Blocks to Fixed document/Fixed Page

Tags: .net, document, fixed

How do I add Blocks(System.Windows.Documents.Block/ Section / BlockUIContainer) to the Fixed Document?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following way:

1. Add block to flowDocument
2. Add flowDocument to FlowDocumentViewer
3. Add FlowDocumentViewer to FixedPage.
4. Then, add this fixed page to pageContent
5. Add pageContent to FixedDocument.Pages

Good luck!